# WCF Data Contract setup to expose System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: vb.net, wcf, datacontract

I have a WCF service that is exposing a custom object which contains multiple properties, one of which is declared as a `List(of String)`. When I call the function through my test app the object that is returned contains a `String()` instead of the list that I expect.

Is there a special tag I need to include for the Data Contract to know that it should treat the properties as `Lists` and not `Arrays`?

Class Definition:

```
<Serializable(), DataContract([Namespace]:="customUrl")> _
Public Class UnitType
    ...
    <DataMember()> Public Units As List(Of String)
    ...
End Class
```

Comment: That's in the "Add Service Reference" dialog - specify List as the collection type.

Comment: Isn't using `Serializable()` and `DataContract()` superfluous, since `DataContract` is serialized?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Will that cause all collections to be pushed into lists? is there a way to tell it to maintain its datatypes instead?

Comment: @Tim: I work for the department of redundancy department. My predecessor wrote these classes and I just inherited all the code. Still trying to figure out what a lot of it is doing so there is probably a lot of useless parts.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien: what do you mean, "maintain its datatypes"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Will Lists stay lists and arrays stay arrays. or will all collections become lists when passed outside of the WCF service?

Comment: @Mike_OBrien: What is the application consuming the WCF service? The answer depends on the consumer.

Comment: @Tim: Serializable and DataContract are only redundant if you always use a serializer that understands data contract. However, some applications allow data to be serialized numerous different ways which would require both attributes. For example, if internally, the objects are serialized across a .net remoting boundary, Serializable will be required and if they are also serialized over WCF to external consumers, DataContract will be required.

Comment: @competent_tech: the application could potentially be anything. The WCF service is basically a way for outside vendors to access our proprietary data structure and get(for the most part) native typed information back to be displayed however they choose. While making a test app I noticed that the lists were becoming arrays and thought I was missing something important. For the most part John Saunders suggestion fixed my issue.